# How would I create a Password Protected Page with Content on it?

Tags: password

How would I create a Password Protected Page with Content on it?

So for example, I want the page to show some content (a little text and some picture, but also require a password.

Is this a template customization or is there a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

On a page or post,

Under the right sidebar "Publish" Click Visibility --> Edit --> Select password protected, set the password.

If you want only partial protection, say only some content, you will need a plugin.